# Response parameter in requestdispatcher

Tags: java, servlets, requestdispatcher

When we forward a request from one servlet to another, using request dispatcher method `forward`, so as the other servlet generates the response, or when we want a response from the other servlet to go back to the one calling, we use include

1. Now forward has two parameters, request and response ,request is client requestwhat is response? A response from servlet1 or servlet two?
2. Same goes for include, what is in response object?  Response from servlet 1, or servlet 2?

Answer (score 1):

**Request Dispatcher** Defines an object that receives requests from the client and sends them to any resource (such as a servlet, HTML file, or JSP file) on the server.

1) Forward :-

```
   Forwards a request from a servlet to another resource (servlet, JSP file, or HTML file) on the server.
```

2) Includes :-

```
   Includes the content of a resource (servlet, JSP page, HTML file) in the response.
```

For more information you can go through the following link. 
[RequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java Doc Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) :
1.For `void forward(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response)`

```
request - a ServletRequest object that represents the request the client makes of the servlet
response - a ServletResponse object that represents the response the servlet returns to the client
```

2.For `void include(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response)`

```
request - a ServletRequest object that contains the client's request
response - a ServletResponse object that contains the servlet's response
```

So in both the cases `response` is the object that use to write or send your servlet response to the client.
`response` is the object from the calling servlet passed to the caller servlet for further processing.

Please refer this link [what is a request dispatcher](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-a-request-dispatcher-and-how-do-i-use-it.html?page=1) it help you understand how it worked.